# Автоматическая горизонтальная прокрутка при наборе текста в Android

Tags: java, android, прокрутка, android-edittext

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при наборе текста в EditText появлялась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки и автоматически, как бы это сказать, "удлинялась". Я попробовал завернуть EditText в HorizontalScrollView, но при вводе текста определённой длины текст переходит на новую строку, тогда как он должен продолжаться печатать по горизонтали. Переходить на следующую строку он должен при нажатии Enter

Вот EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:padding="15dp" />
```

Comment: android:maxLines="1"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <EditText
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp" />
```

Comment: не работает, все равно переходит на следующую строку, тогда как переходить должно только при нажатии Enter